# Output code from Ruby on Rails block without closing ruby tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codeblocks

Ok this may seem stupid and I have googled extensively using various different keywords and terms, attempted a lot of various different methods and tried to my very last breadth and cannot seem to figure out how to do this. All I want is stdout in a rails app without needing to break my block.

Currently, when I do a block of ruby code in my rails app and want to output the value I do the following

```
<% somearray do | item | %>
    <%= item %>
<% end %>
```

To me this is quite messy, I know coming from a PHP background it's not how one should imagine how to code in rails but coming from **many different** environments I like my code to look nice *to me*. It's very easy to encapsulate every single line with <% %> but I'd prefer my code to be my code and my mark up to be my mark up.

What I'd like, but which doesn't work, is....

```
<%
    somearray do | item |
        whatever item #whatever being puts or similar
    end
%>
```

It's solely for the aesthetics of the code and not for what it produces but for me, a very long time programmer, it means a lot and a lot of time saved when trying to see where and when code blocks begin and end.

Thanks in advance,

Jay (c0ld)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat`. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat):

> The preferred method of outputting text in your views is to use the `<%= “text” %>` eRuby syntax. .... If you absolutely must output text within a non-output code block (i.e., `<% %>`), you can use the `concat` method.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> <%
>     concat "hello"
>     # is the equivalent of <%= "hello" %>
>
>     if logged_in
>       concat "Logged in!"
>     else
>       concat link_to('login', :action => login)
>     end
>     # will either display "Logged in!" or a login link
> %>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
<%= somearray.map {|item| item }.join(" ") %>
```

P.S. of course if item just outputs itself - it can be even shorter